# Windows doesn't detect that my Hardware Virtualization is enabled

Tags: android, hardware-acceleration

well i tried to install Intel HAXM because i couldn't create my avd in Android Studio but it gave me error that "My computer doesn't support the technology" , then i went to my BIOS settings but the hardware virtualization was already enabled.I don't understand what the reason is , i have searched a lot about it but no luck. And i don't have any antivirus . I just have my windows defender so that's not a problem either.

What i have tried is:

1.Reboot pc and disable HV.

2.Reboot again and enable the HV.

But it still doesn't work.Please help someone. I'll really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what CPU do you have - need to check it supports VT (virtualization) and XD/ND - disable bit. You can do that at ark.intel.com

Comment: Thanks for the answer and yeah i checked , it doesn't have the technology :( . Then why the heck would they even put an option for enabling or disabling when it doesn't even work -_- . Anyways thank u.

Comment: ohh one question actually if i never had the technology , then how was i able to create an avd in my eclipse ??